# Does Google Fit API only works with gmail account?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm trying to use Fitness API services on my app and it was running well so far. I can obtain any data that I need from Google Fit until it wont work anymore when I'm using corporate account outside gmail, for example `account@biz-corporate.com`. So what I want to know is, does Fitness API only works with gmail account? They do not mention anything about that on the authorization pages:

- https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/authorization
- https://developers.google.com/identity/#google-sign-in

It would be nice if someone can point me out to a relevant article or something similar. Thank you.